# Firebase data message to specific android app versions

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

i have an android app and i want to send a firebase data message to inform the users of a new app version available in the play store. I am sending a data message in order to reach devices in which the app is in background.
I want send the message to specific versions, or if it's possible to all versions except the last version.
What is the best way to do it? Can I specify a version number in a fcm data message?
Below is the data message i am sending.

Thanks in advance.

```
{
  "to": "/topics/all",
  "data": {
    "title": "new version",
    "body": "a new version is available in play store"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have answer for your question but I can suggest another way to achieve your case.
Take a look at [Firebase Remote Config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config).

You can define variable for your client to get anytime it start.
So for your case, we have 3 variable:

`destinationVersion` for your *specific version*

`title`

`message`

In the app, just put the logic like if app's version equal to `destinationVersion` , create a notification with `title` and `message` to tell user update the app
. Hope it helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can force users to update with Google now: https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates#immediate